# Could it be possible to define an array with a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code that uses arrays whose dimension depends of values that the user gives. This value depends on the number of cells that he/she is using and I use this number to do a for-loop structure. 
Here it´s an example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Myarray(1 To Row) As String

    For 1 To Row
        'Do whatever I need
    Next linha
End Sub
```

When I tried this, an error appears. Is there any way to use that? I was looking for any clues on google and I found dynamic array. But it dosen´t seem to fit in my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the syntax to (obviously `LengthOfArray' should hold a number with the size of the array):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Myarray() As String

    n = LengthOfArray

    Redim MyArray(1 to LengthOfArray)

    For linha = 1 To n
        'Do whatever I need
    Next linha
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a collection instead of an array and you may want to look into doing redim preserve. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)

```
sub Test(row as range)
Dim my myCollection as new collection


myCollection.add row
For each Item in myCollection
    'Do some stuff here...
Next 'Item
end Sub
```